# C socket - recv: connection reset by peer

Tags: c, sockets, send, recv

All is doing fine here, except that the client can't receive the message, or the server can't send it, I don't know.
I have really little time, so I can't waste it anymore trying to handle this problem, so I turn to you guys. Just one thing that I think (maybe) you have to know: the server is under my network, the client is under my school network.
P.S. the different IPs for the server is because I'm behind a NAT, no problem with that.

**Client code**

```
const char* IPSERVER = "87.21.70.136";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

struct addrinfo hints, *serverInfo;
int s;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // AF_INET or AF_INET6 to force version
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

if(getaddrinfo(IPSERVER, "50", &hints, &serverInfo) != 0){
    printf("Errore getaddrinfo(). Chiusura...\n");
    exit(-1);
}

s = socket(serverInfo->ai_family, serverInfo->ai_socktype, serverInfo->ai_protocol);
printf("Porta: %d\n", ((struct sockaddr_in * ) serverInfo->ai_addr)->sin_port);

if(connect(s, serverInfo->ai_addr, serverInfo->ai_addrlen) < 0)
    perror("Errore connect()");

char buf[2000];
int bytes_rec;
if((bytes_rec = recv(s, buf, sizeof buf, 0)) < 0)
    perror("Errore recv");
printf("%s\n",buf);
close(s);

return 0;

}
```

**Server code**

```
struct sockaddr_storage clientAddr;
socklen_t addrSize;
struct addrinfo hints, *myInfo;
int s, newS;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;  // use IPv4 or IPv6, whichever
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

if(getaddrinfo("192.168.1.2", "50", &hints, &myInfo) < 0)
    perror("Errore getaddrinfo()");
printf("Porta: %d\n", ((struct sockaddr_in *) myInfo->ai_addr) -> sin_port);
s = socket(myInfo->ai_family, myInfo->ai_socktype, myInfo->ai_protocol);
if(s < 0)
    perror("Errore socket()");
printf("Socket stabilita.\n");
if(bind(s, myInfo->ai_addr, myInfo->ai_addrlen) < 0)
 perror("Errore bind()");
printf("Porta creata.\n");
if(listen(s, 5) < 0)
    perror("Errore listen()");
printf("Server in ascolto...\n");
addrSize = sizeof clientAddr;
if((newS = accept(s, (struct sockaddr * )&clientAddr, &addrSize) < 0))
   perror("Errore accept()");
printf("Invio messaggio in corso...\n");
char *msg = "ciao, mi vedi?";
int len, bytes_sent;
len = strlen(msg);
if((bytes_sent = send(newS, msg, len, 0)) < 0)
    perror("Errore send()");
printf("Messaggio inviato.\n");
closesocket(newS);
closesocket(s);
WSACleanup();

return 0;

}
```

**Client output**

```
Porta: 12800
Errore recv: Connection reset by peer
```

**Server output**

```
Porta: 12800
Socket stabilita.
Porta creata.
Server in ascolto...
Invio messaggio in corso...
Errore send(): No error
Messaggio inviato.

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 4.789 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: When printing the `sin_port` value, you need to use `ntohs()`.  12800 is 50 expressed in network byte order, so flip it to host byte order before printing it.  Also, `recv()` does not null-terminate the buffer, so you have to do that manually, or better use `%.*s` so you can pass `bytes_rec` to `printf()`.

Comment: The real problem here is `perror()` printing `no error` after the `send()` error. I suspect more firewall issues, as in your [previous question with the same code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600160/c-sockets-cannot-bind-server-public-ip). NB If you get an error on a system call, it is mostly quite invalid to continue as though it hadn't happened. Errors in `socket(), listen(), bind(), connect(), accept()` are fatal to this code, and should cause exits or returns.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll try tomorrow.

Comment: On a side note, you should not be using `AF_UNSPEC` since the rest of your code is assuming IPv4 (by your use of `sockaddr_in`).  Use `AF_INET` instead.

Comment: Of course. I didnt think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server code is clearly using the WinSock API, which means the server is running on Windows.

Socket handles on Windows are unsigned values, so `int` is the wrong data type to use for them. You need to use the `SOCKET` type instead.  And compare the return value of `socket()` and `accept()` again the `INVALID_SOCKET` constant.

Ignoring socket creation errors and passing invalid sockets to `send()` and `recv()` can cause them to fail.

`perror()` operates on `errno`, which WinSock (and the Win32 API in general) does not use.  That would explain the `"no error"` message after `send()` fails, because `errno` is 0.  You have to use `WSAGetLastError()` instead to get a WinSock error code when a WinSock function fails.

With that said, try this server code:

```
void psocketerror(const char *msg, int err)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %d\n", msg, err);
}

void psocketerror(const char *msg)
{
    psocketerror(msg, WSAgetLastError());
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_storage clientAddr;
    socklen_t addrSize;
    struct addrinfo hints, *myInfo;
    SOCKET s, newS;
    int err;

    WSADATA wsa;
    err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsa);
    if (err != 0) {
        psocketerror("Errore WSAStartup()", err);
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if ((err = getaddrinfo("192.168.1.2", "50", &hints, &myInfo)) < 0) {
        psocketerror("Errore getaddrinfo()", err);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Porta: %d\n", ntohs(((struct sockaddr_in *)(myInfo->ai_addr))->sin_port));

    s = socket(myInfo->ai_family, myInfo->ai_socktype, myInfo->ai_protocol);
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        psocketerror("Errore socket()");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Socket stabilita.\n");

    if (bind(s, myInfo->ai_addr, myInfo->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
        psocketerror("Errore bind()");
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Porta creata.\n");

    if (listen(s, 5) < 0) {
        psocketerror("Errore listen()");
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Server in ascolto...\n");

    addrSize = sizeof clientAddr;
    newS = accept(s, (struct sockaddr * )&clientAddr, &addrSize)
    if (newS === INVALID_SOCKET) {
        psocketerror("Errore accept()");
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Invio messaggio in corso...\n");

    char *msg = "ciao, mi vedi?";
    int len, bytes_sent;
    len = strlen(msg);

    if ((bytes_sent = send(newS, msg, len, 0)) < 0) {
        psocketerror("Errore send()");
        closesocket(newS);
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Messaggio inviato.\n");

    closesocket(newS);
    closesocket(s);

    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try tomorrow.

Comment: I tried your code it works, thanks. Obv just had to change the printfs with fprintf. About the client, I noticed that with %.*s it prints random characters, instead with %s and without manually terminating the array with \0 it normally prints the string received. Just saying.

Comment: `%.*s` works fine if you use it correctly, eg: `printf("%.*s\n", bytes_rec, buf);`.  Specifying a precision for `%s` tells `printf()` the maximum number of characters to print so the buffer does not need to be null-terminated. The `*` simply tells `printf()` to get the precision value from the argument list instead of the format string. If you don't specify a precision for `%s`, the buffer must be null-terminated, or else it will exceed the bounds of the buffer and print data from surrounding memory if the buffer does not contain any embedded null characters.

Comment: Oh I see. Didn't know that. Thanks for this useful tip.